# Is there a bug in this step (and how to fix it?)

Tags: rotational-dynamics, relative-motion, free-fall, textbook-erratum

Reading an old book of classical mechanics (Spiegel's theoretical mechanics) I came across a passage that I would like to clarify. In order to find the equations of motion of free falling point particle that regulate motion according to a laboratory on to the earth's surface, the relative acceleration theorem is exploited. In a step (red arrow) apparent gravitational field is introduced to get (6), and then (7) ($\mathbf{r}$ the "small" vector from laboratory origin to the point, the triple vector product has magnitude something like $h\cdot 10^{-9}$). But later (blue arrow) the apparent field is written as $-g\mathbf{k}$ where $\mathbf{k}$ is the laboratory $z$ versor, orthogonal to the ground, toward the sky. Isn't this a bug? The direction of apparent field is not $\mathbf{k}$. Of course the effect is small, but Coriolis force too is small. If this is not a bug, why? If this is a bug, how to fix It?

**Edit**

The problem is that $\mathbf{g}$ does not represent the *real* gravitational field but the direction of the plumb line (this is the meaning of the choice in equation (5)). Therefore it has not the direction of the versor $-\mathbf{k}$. The effect is small but the discussion assumes without justifying it that it is negligible compared to that of Coriolis. How can I justify it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried comparing the magnitudes of the two forces for *h* on the order of a few meters? $h\cdot 10^{-9}$ is a fairly negligible number at that height. They do mention immediately under your red arrow that this is done to *great approximation* near the Earth's surface.

Comment: @Triatticus Of course I understand this negligible triple vector product. I thank you for the interest but you misunderstood my question: it is easy to see what happens from (6) to (7) but I can't understand why with blue arrow the apparent gravitational field is supposed to have $\textbf{k}$ direction: this approximation should be justified as I did with the approximation (6) to (7) after the red arrow.

Comment: Oh wait I'm looking at it now, no they are correct, because the gravitational field of a perfect sphere is directed perpendicularly into the surface, the deviation comes from the part after $-g\hat{k}$ (since it has components in both the $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ directions). In the limit $\omega\to 0$ you should recover a perfectly perpendicular direction of g at all angles.

Comment: @Triatticus but in $\omega\to 0$ limit, Coriolis force too is zero. The book is ignoring the rotation effect of the not ground orthogonal direction of apparent field but not ignoring the rotation effect of Coriolis force. I don't say this is wrong, but it is not justified. I would like to put a patch on it to fix the proof but I can't do it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your issue, it can't be with the $-g\hat{k}$ term as that part is only dependant on the shape and mass distribution of the object (here a sphere) and has nothing to do with rotation. So it's the rest of the terms (the coriolis term)? I'm a little unsure what your last comment meant to say maybe some letters got jumbled around. Maybe you can edit the question with how you think the derivation should look.